# Exchanging data between steps in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job that is built of the following components

1. Processing Step - activates an external processing that logs it's result in the DB and returns an **internal id** so I can take this id and process it further
2. Logging Step - built of a tasklet, that contains a chunk

The chunk is built of an item reader - that I plan will use **#{stepExecutionContext['job.id']}** as part of the sql written in the xml file so it will get the relevant logging info

I'm trying to work with the solution suggested here - [11.8 Passing Data to Future Steps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/patterns.html) but i get this error when i try to add a property on the **step execution context** or the **job execution context**

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecutionContext().put("job.id", jobId);
```

And I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1342)
at  ...
at  org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
```

Did i miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StepContext available from ChunkContext is a read-only object; use a `StepExecutionListener` and save the step execution context passed as parameter in method `StepExecutionListener.afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)`

Comment: I realize this is an old question. I want to get the context into my reader. The reason is that it's parsing an Excel file and knows the full amount of records to be read, in advance. However, using Spring ...readCount() functions seems to reflect the read count thus far, but not the total amount read. How can I get the context from here into the Reader?

Answer (score 1):

I always follow this path:

```
chunkContext
    .getStepContext()
    .getStepExecution()
    .getJobExecution()
    .getExecutionContext()
    .put("", "");
```

I also had problems doing the put in StepExecution. 
Maybe it loses data when it goes to the next step.
However, I leave the last sentence to the most expert.

Answer (score 0):

chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecutionContext() retrun copy use chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext()

Comment: Please add some explanation on your answer.